# Nokia HERE - Mobile HTML5 Map - 404 errors

Tags: here-api

I am seeing a lot of 404 Not Found errors for the url: http://b.heatmaps.maps.svc.ovi.com/heatmaps/v2/mapsymbols.default/13/2135/3100/1024/jsonp?app_id=&app_code=&xnlp=CL_MH5v1.0.2%2CSID_92d66a5d2f7340c6ac2b1cd10c7ec89b. I can't figure out why a call is being made to that endpoint because the source is minified. Has anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is due to the framework requesting mini-icon images highlighting places on the map. I guess that the particular image requested is unavailable at this time. You can see the difference in the two images below (one from `m.here.com`, the other from an mh5app)

[image: m.here.com]

This is an image from m.here.com

[image: mobile HTML5 framework]

This is the same image using the mobile HTML5 framework

It is possible to disable the download of all such items with the following:

```
nokia.mh5.app.controller.current.page.map._cartoPOI.deactivate()
```

I no longer get the 404s when I add this line.